# Problemas no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, banco-de-dados

Oi, pessoal!
Sou novo com PHP e Banco de Dados MySQL.

Há vários dias estou quebrando a cabeça com um código e não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro de jeito nenhum. :/

Tenho uma página index.php, com um form chamando o arquivo "cep.php". Neste arquivo, preciso que o comando leia o input enviado pelo usuário, e confira se os dados inseridos no existem na tabela "cep", no campo "CEP".

Se o cep existir no bd, redireciona para a página "ok.php"
Se não existir, ele redireciona para a página "bad.php".

index.php:

```
<form method="post" action="cep.php" >
   <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Digite seu CEP" name="cepinput" id="cepinput" maxlength="9" OnKeyPress="formatar('#####-###', this)" />
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Verificar Disponibilidade" />
</form>
```

cep.php:

```
<?php

require "conexao.php";

// Recuperamos o cep enviado pelo formulário
$cep = $_GET['cepinput'];

// Verificamos no banco de dados o cep equivalente
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cep WHERE CEP=$cep");

// Descobrimos o total de registros encontrados
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($resultado);

// Se houver o cep informado
if ($num_rows > 0) {

// Exibe a página OK
$url = 'ok.php';
echo'<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';  

// Se não houver o cep informado
} 
else {
$urlerro = 'bad.php';
echo'<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$urlerro.'">';  
}

?>
```

O erro acontece quando aperto o botão "submit". Ele retorna a página "bad.php", mesmo que eu insira um cep existente no BD.

Desde já, muito obrigado! ;)

Comment: Qual o erro que está dando? Note que você não precisa dessa variável $url nem $urlerro

Comment: Ola, Renato!
Obrigado pela resposta.

Então, o erro é que quando aperto o botão "submit", ele retorna a página "bad.php", mesmo que eu insira um cep existente no BD.

Quanto a não precisar da variável, em qual linha você diz?

Grato.

Comment: Ponha um CEP válido e veja se o mysql_num_rows está retornando a quantidade real, caso esteja tente redirecionar assim
header("location: ok.php");

Comment: Não faltou aspas simples no sql? `SELECT * FROM cep WHERE CEP='$cep'` ?

Comment: Realmente, faltava aspas simples! Não tinha me atentado para isso.
Melhor fazer com header mesmo, Paul! Muito obrigado pela ajuda, pessoal!!

Comment: Por que ao invés de usar `meta refresh` você não opta por utilizar o comando `header('location:destino.php');` para fazer o redirecionamento?

Comment: Fiz isso, Adriano! Valeu pela dica! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tente com PDO é mais seguro, utilize este algorítimo aqui e veja se gosta, está testado e funciona.

```
<?php try { $conect = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $mysql_host . "; dbname=" . $mysql_base, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
    $conect -> setAttribute(PDO :: ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO :: ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conect -> exec("set names utf8");
    $statement = $conect -> prepare("SELECT * FROM cep WHERE CEP = :cep");
    $statement_array = array(':cep' => $_GET["cepinput"]);
    foreach($statement_array as $array_key => $bindvalue) {
        $statement -> bindValue($array_key, $bindvalue); }
    $statement -> execute();
    $statement = $statement -> fetchAll();
    if(count($statement)) {
        $url = 'ok.php';
        echo'<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
    } else {
        $urlerro = 'bad.php';
        echo'<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$urlerro.'">';
    }
$conect = null; } catch(PDOException $error) { echo $error -> getMessage(); }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica de segurança, amigo! No caso, eu tenho um arquivo conexao.php separado. Insiro as 3 primeiras linhas nele e o restante em meu cep.php? Obrigado!

Comment: você só precisa colocar o banco de dados, o usuário e a senha, o resto ele faz para você, não precisa do arquivo conexao.php pois ele irá retornar em count se existe ou não o cep digitado só tente evitar * no select ou seja, de SELECT * FROM cep WHERE CEP = :cep ponha SELECT CEP FROM cep WHERE CEP = :cep, troque as variaveis pelos valores delas ou ponha dentro do conexao.php

Comment: Legal!! Vou tentar usar ele! ;) Brigadão!!